# Alexa Request Customer contact Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am observing a very weird behavior in Requesting Customer Contact information, email in my skill's case.

I have implemented the exact same way as mentioned in the documentation. I have provided the permission in the skill's permission tab (for email). I have granted the permission in the app and from the code, I am calling the following REST API for fetching email id of the user by passing Bearer token (consent token in permissions object received in JSON input)

```
https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com/v2/accounts/~current/settings/Profile.email
```

But the weird thing is, that recently, I am getting this response

> {'code': 'ACCESS_DENIED', 'message': 'Authentication failure with
>   reason: TOKEN_INVALID'}

I have been recently facing this issue that sometimes the API is working fine but sometimes, it is not and I am receiving the above errors.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

> I am calling the following REST API for fetching email id of the user
>   by passing Bearer token (consent token in permissions object received
>   in JSON input)

According to this [doc](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/device-address-api.html), `consentToken` has been deprecated, you should use `apiAccessToken` instead.

> Important: Requests from Alexa may also include a `consentToken` within
>   `session.user.permissions` and `context.System.user.permissions`. This
>   property is deprecated. Existing skills that use `consentToken` continue
>   to work, but the `context.System.apiAccessToken` property should be used
>   instead.

Thus, [`accessToken = this.event.context.System.apiAccessToken`](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-customer-contact-information-for-use-in-your-skill.html#get-the-api-access-token).

Also, double-check your header: `{"Authorization": "Bearer " + apiAccessToken}`, make sure you have a space between `Bearer` and `apiAccessToken`.

Comment: I am getting the same access denied with both tokens. I tried with apiAccessToken as well. Getting the same response.

Comment: it is behaving in an inappropriate matter, like it is working fine in my android device but gives error in my friends iphone.